# wp8 HttpWebRequest POST not sending post values along

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, post, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

Im kind of stuck with a HttpWebRequest while sending post values and i dont know what the problem is.

Hopefully anyone is able to help me with this.

this is my code

```
private async void loggingIn(string url, string postdata)
    {
        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            try
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url)) as HttpWebRequest;
                request.Method = "POST";

                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;
                using (var requestStream = await Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, request))
                {
                    await requestStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                }


                WebResponse responseObject = await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, request);
                var responseStream = responseObject.GetResponseStream();
                var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                MessageBox.Show(received);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "localhost/test.php";
        string password = passwordBoxLogin.Password;
        string username = usernameBoxLogin.Text;

        string postdata = "password=" + password +"&username="+username;

        loggingIn(url,postdata);
    }
```

The problem is that my server does not receive any values from the POST request.
but i do get a response from the server.

this is what i use to check the code on my php server

```
<?php
   echo $_POST['username'];
   echo"-";
   echo $_POST['password'];
?>
```

the only thing i get returned is the -

Thanks in advance for helping me out :)

It just started working without anychanges.

For now case closed!

Answer (score 0):

I modified You Code Like this 
Hope it's definitely Work for You

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "localhost/test.php";
        string password = passwordBoxLogin.Password;
        string username = usernameBoxLogin.Text;
        string postdata = "password=" + password +"&username="+username;

        bool isNetwork = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
        if (!isNetwork)
        {
        }
        else
        {
         try
          {

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"; // Your Application Header Content-Type 
            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(proxy_UploadStringCompleted);
            webClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(url ), "POST", postdata ,null);
          }
          catch
          {
          }
        }

    }

    private void proxy_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var response = e.Result;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it may help you.

```
private async void loggingIn(string url, string postdata)
        {
            if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                try
                {
                 var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;  
                 request.Method = "POST";
                 request.Accept = "application/json";
                 request.ContentType = "application/json";
                 request.BeginGetRequestStream(loginRequest, request);
                 }
                 catch(Exception ex) 
                {
                }
       }
     private void loginRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
      {
       string postdata = "password=" + password +"&username="+username;
       UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
       Stream _body = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult);
       byte[] formBytes = encoding.GetBytes(postdata);
       _body.Write(formBytes, 0, formBytes.Length);
       _body.Close();
        request.BeginGetResponse(loginResponse, request);
      }

     private void loginResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
      {
         try
          {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
            using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
            {
            string received = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(received);
            }
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
         {
         }
     }
```