# Pass POST variables with Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to insert Data from a Windows Phone App into a Database using a php script.
This is my C# code I execute when clicking on a button.

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("xxx/Insert.php")) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
string postdata = "Title=test&CategoryID=1";
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
using (var requestStream = await Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, request))
{
    await requestStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

I get the variable in the php script with

```
<?php
$title = $_POST["Title"];
$categoryID = $_POST["CategoryID"];
...
?>
```

Someone had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961669/wp8-httpwebrequest-post-not-sending-post-values-along), but the solution didn't work, because
1.) WebClient is not available for WP8
2.) The second solution throws an Exception in App.i.g.cs at the line global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()

The problem is simply nothing happens. Has anybody encountered with the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem using System.Net.Http.HttpClient and System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("baseUrl.net");
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Title", "test")
            });

                var result = await client.PostAsync("/insert.php", content);
                string resultContent = "result: "+result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

EDIT: awaiting the PostAsync of the client